# Crashing iOS app after creating a new view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm just starting to learn creating iOS apps and so I'm just a noob in it. Especially because of the different approach it has on handling navigation and interaction between UI and Code. :)

Ok I'm using xCode 5 with SDK version 7. I created a single view application and it gave me a `.storyboard` file which I guess replaces the `.xib` which used to be there when I watch tutorial videos.

So I designed a simple UI as the `main` view and now I want to have another view as the `landing` view. So it should come in before the `main` view. I went ahead and from `New File...` I created an Objective-C class which is a subclass of `UIViewController` and named it `Detail`. Surprisingly it gave me a `.xib` file again. Fair enough. Then I just put a simple input in the UI to just preview it.

Then from Project Settings, in the General tab, I changed the `Main Interface` to match the new `.xib` file I created. But when I launched the application, it crashed and I don't know what the problem is.

Here is the stack trace:

```
2013-11-27 18:31:21.735 TestViewSwitching[10123:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x8b35dc0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0174c5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bb8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017dc6a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x0117c9ee -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x010e8cfb _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
    5   Foundation                          0x010e8253 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    6   Foundation                          0x0114a70a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
    7   UIKit                               0x004cba15 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014cd7d2 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x01747b6a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
    10  UIKit                               0x004ca56e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
    11  UIKit                               0x004cc2fb -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 165
    12  UIKit                               0x002293bb -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 58
    13  UIKit                               0x002296e9 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 245
    14  UIKit                               0x0022828f -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 543
    15  UIKit                               0x0023c87c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    16  UIKit                               0x0023cde9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    17  UIKit                               0x0022a025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x036df2f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x036dee01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x016c7d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x016c7a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x016f277c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x016f1ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x016f18db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    25  UIKit                               0x00227add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    26  UIKit                               0x00229d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    27  TestViewSwitching                   0x0000211d main + 141
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d7670d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This process in Android is pretty straight forward, but I don't know why Apple tries to make everything harder for developers. They couldn't just set up a type which generates a new view ready to go?

Comment: It would be easier as a beginner to stick with all storyboard instead of mixing storyboard and xibs. When you create you view controller subclass, don't check the xib button. Instead, drag out another controller in the storyboard and change its class with the inspector to your subclass. You can then hook up any segues you want to move between the controllers.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for your comment. But I'm just curious to know what the problem is.. Because in the video tutorials I watch they just create it and it works right away..

Comment: It's hard to say, but it's probably something you set up wrong in the storyboard or xib. It looks like from the error, that you're trying to set the value of something with the key "view" which the class you setting it in doesn't have.

Comment: @rdelmar The fact is I tried to do it with a new and clean project and the same thing happens. Nothing in the classes. I don't touch any code. I just drag two fields into the views.

Comment: These are the kind of problems that are hard to fix without actually seeing the project, since the problem is probably something in the xib or storyboard -- some object you have made in IB must be calling that method.

Comment: I know, but I just don't do anything. I create a project, I create a new UIViewController class, set the Main Interface to the new class. That's it and it crashes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42083/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-miro-markarian)

Answer (score 3):

@Miro Markarian , you may check the .xib file for view outlet.It may be be disconnected or broken.This issue generally arises due to that.Try to add the outlet of the view controller's view to the .xib view.

Answer (score 0):

Your view outlet on your main view controller's `.xib` is not connected to its `file owner` properly.